# How can i get single document from Firestore with query (I'm using Ionic 4 )

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4

Good morning , I have database in firestore below :

```
**collections**       **documents**     **fields** 
123                     news1           title:{some data}
                        news2           content:{some data}
```

for example i want to get the all data of the (news1) in the page of my ionc4 app , how can i do that please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by querying specific document id:

```
firestore.collection(collectionName).doc(documentId).valueChanges()
.subscribe(singleDoc =>{
console.log(singleDoc)
});
```

For you the query will look like this:

```
firestore.collection('123').doc('news1').valueChanges()
.subscribe(news1=>{
console.log(news1)
});
```

Comment: what if i dont have the documentId?
pls help me

Comment: then you can get the list of documents.

Comment: Any update on this? I am trying to execute the following query 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CONDITION1 AND CONDITION2'. Basically, it will return a single record if the data exists in the collection. I am doing the same but I am getting a result that is confusing me.